# Use Notification center to trigger function inside if statement

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I would like to use the notification center inside an if statement to trigger a function (`setupPlayerView`) whenever the user scrolls from one page to another (all that happens in a scrollview with paging enabled): I want to setup a video player in certain views. To be more precise I would like the current and the following page to setup a video player. Each page contains a video player (or rather *can* contain a video player since I want to set them up only when called). To achieve this I use a class called `PlayerView` (in a for loop inside my scrollview because it's the same for each page) in which I have the function setting up the video player and in which I also have the following code to receive notifications from the notification center:

```
var urlString: String?
var pageNo: String?
var called = false

override init(frame: CGRect){

    //...

    if self.called == false, self.urlString != nil, self.pageNo != nil {

        if self.pageNo == "0" {

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.setupPlayerView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "0 1"), object: nil)

        }
        else {

            let previousPage = String(Int(self.pageNo!)! - 1)

            let rawString = previousPage + " " + self.pageNo!

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.setupPlayerView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: rawString), object: nil)

        }

    }

}
```

As you can see all this is only possible if certain variables are set. These variables are set also set through the scrollview as seen in the following code (inside the for loop in scrollview since it's for each page):

```
let videoUrl =  "https://testvideo.mov"

let pageNoInPlayer = pageIndex

//add Subview with videoplayer frame to individual "pages"
let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageSize.width, height: pageSize.height) //page covers entire screen
let videoPlayerView = PlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)

videoPlayerView.urlString = videoUrl
videoPlayerView.pageNo = String(pageNoInPlayer)
```

The functions responsible for posting the notifications works fine if I give it some constant `rawValue` and the "reception" (observer) in the `PlayerView` class the same `rawValue` outside the if statement. Why isn't it being called when the notifications are posted? Is it because of the if? The values should have been set by then...

To test if the values are set I used `didSet` which worked:

```
var urlString: String? {

    didSet {

        print(urlString ?? String())

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rawValue serves to identify the notification; generally, this should be a constant value (not some string determined at runtime). Additionally, the code you've shown *conditionally* adds the notification observer. More likely, you want something like this:

```
override init(frame: CGRect){

//...
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.setupPlayerView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: someConstant), object: nil)

}

func setupPlayerView() {
    if (isCurrentView && otherConditions) {
        // do whatever you want 
    }
}
```

Note that the notification is added regardless of the state of the class at initialization. Init() is only (usually) called once; switching pages in a UIPageViewController will temporarily store previous view controllers without reinitializing in order to increase efficiency.

One more thing: Using NotificationCenter is often a patch for poorly organized code. It's likely that there's a better way to structure your logic, but I can't comment further based solely on the code you've provided.

Comment: But I only want the (visible page and) the following one to be called so that the video preloads. I want to pass on information. Your method wouldn't provide this as one would never know what page is visible since that information can only be provided by the scrollview class... What would you suggest me to do to achieve my goal... I am quite new to swift so I couldn't think of another way :/

Comment: Oh, I misread- you're using a scrollview with paging? You should be using a UIPageViewController. A scrollview will always loaded every page, whereas a pageviewcontroller will dynamically load pages as the user navigates to them.

Comment: Could you give me your e mail adress so that you could help me regarding the page view controller and how you would approach the problem to solve it? I don't have a lot of experience with pageviewcontrollers and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your PlayerView initialiser to

init(frame: CGRect, pageNo: String, urlString: String)

and pass pageNo and urlString as argument because before assign value to pageNo, urlString initialiser executed and if condition

if self.called == false, self.urlString != nil, self.pageNo != nil

becomes false.